# Sending a https request to a http server -- Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Recently i came across an issue that keeps disturbing me and have tried everything without a result. I am fetching a feed from a different news source and i used a jquery

```
 $.get('//js.mysite.com/javascript.php', options, function(xml) {

             },
            'xml'
        );
```

My code works fine for many days unti yesterday suddenly it stoped working on the hosted site and work on the developement machine. The page returns null with a response code 404 with an error message `xmlhttprequest cannot load is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin` . I then proceed and modify my code to support the said cross domain support as suggested  [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.my/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html).

```
 $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : '//js.mysite.com/javascript.php' + "?callback=?",
            data : options,
            dataType : 'xml',
            success : function(xml) {
           ....
            },

            jsonp: 'jsonp'

        });
```

The above works at the localhost as well. However i keep getting the `xmlRequest` error message .

When i inspect then i realized, my `Request Url` on localhost return `http` While on the hosted machine , it shows `https` .  Following the two links, the first one works . Please how do i addressed this ? The link when `https` added it does not work .

```
http://js.mysite.com/javascript.php?callback=?&prefix=prefix&media=2&campaign=1&mode=txt
```

the above is as returned by the localhost, and

```
https://js.mysite.com/javascript.php?callback=?&prefix=prefix&media=2&campaign=1&mode=txt
```

Returned on the hosted machine.

Any help , suggestion or better explanation would highly be appreciated.

Comment: you have ssl problems

Comment: try using ssl on the ajax page see if ti works

Comment: ssl on the ajax page ? You mean to bypass it or to enable it on the header ? Please can you give example @madalinivascu

Comment: to be enabled on the page that you do ajax